# Read keyboard input in Scala with the typed characters visible

Tags: scala, console, user-input

I know about `readInt` and `readLine` similar methods for reading input from the keyboard and am able to populate variables with the data typed by the user. But in the REPL nothing is displayed when the characters are being typed.  Is there a setting in the REPL to make them visible?  Or should I use some other way of reading input from the user?

Comment: @om-nom-nom - That doesn't show you what you're typing, only what you've typed after you press enter (when it's presumably too late).

Comment: If I take a class file that was compiled from Scala code and run it using `java.exe`, the characters are visible as I type, without having to write code to display them.  The completed application will be run with `java.exe`, so I don't want to write code for this only because of the behavior of the REPL.

Comment: I think the Scala REPL (still) uses JLine. You can probably dig around in the REPL source and find out how to get to the relevant objects and call the right method to alter the input behavior. ... I hope that's vague enough for you...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm surprised this hasn't been answered yet. I ran into the same problem awhile back. Try running the REPL like this:

```
C:\> scala -Xnojline
```

This should disable JLine and allow you to use the `readLine` method the way you would expect (displaying characters typed as you type them).

Comment: This solved the problem of no echo on REPL for me with Scala 2.11.12 on Ubuntu 18.04. It breaks arrow keys, though.